# How do I fix the UVs on this propane tank?

Tags: import

So I was trying to find a way to convert an FBX file from ASCII FBX to Binary FBX and when I converted it this happened and I did some research and found out that it was that the UVs were messed up. I'm very much a noob when it comes to Blender and I have no idea what those are and how to fix this. Is there anyone that could help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually an issue with the normals of you mesh, which is the direction the faces are pointing/facing. You can recalculate the normals by selecting all of the mesh in edit mode and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. This could be resulting from double vertices, so you could try removing doubles with <kbd>W</kbd>, again in edit mode with all selected. This may affect the exported file (assuming you are exporting it) in an undesirable way, so just be careful and have a backup.